# Trajectories approaching an unstable equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $V$ be a $C^k$ vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an equilibrium point of $V$, and $J = DV(x)$ be the corresponding Jacobian matrix. Assume that $J$ has an eigenvalue with positive real part. Can exist an open set $U$ such that all trajectories assotiated to $V$ starting in $U$ converges to $x$ when the time goes to infinity?

Comment: Don't you need negative real part? And you need **ALL** eigenvalues with this property.

Comment: I am not assuming that $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: How about the eigenvalues? If $V(x) = x$, no trajectory converges to $0$.

Comment: Hint: you can't do this with hyperbolic equilibria, but non-hyperbolic could work, even when Jacobi matrix has positive eigenvalue.

Comment: What do you mean by $V(x) = x$, @ArcticChar?

Comment: I mean if the vector field is $V(x_1, \cdots, x_n)  =(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, then $0$ is an equilibrium, the jacobian at $0$ is the identity matrix, which has positive eigenvalues. In this case no trajectory converges to $0$.

Comment: I am asking exactly about the non-hyperbolic case, @Evgeny. Do you have a simple example where such $U$ exists?

Comment: @ArcticChar, if $V(x,y) = (x,-y)$, then $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium, $J$ has one positive and one negative eigenvalue, and the trajectory starting in the $y$-axis converges to $(0,0)$. But this is a hyperbolic equilibrium point, so there exists no such $U$ that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes, that's because it has a negative eigenvalue. That's why I am asking if your $J$ has **negative** eigenvalues instead of positive. Positive eigenvalues does not help.

Comment: I am assuming the existence of only one eigenvalue with positive real part, not all of them.

Comment: @MauroPatrão My bad, it seems that I've overlooked one fact in my idea. At first I thought that a saddle node $V(x, y) = (x^2, -y)$ would work, but it has only a zero and negative eigenvalue. So, I don't have an example for your question right now.

Comment: Now I think the answer is "no". Such open set $U$ must belong to center-stable manifold $W^{cs}(x)$, hence it's dimension must be $n$ — the same as the dimension of the whole phase space. But ${\rm dim}\, W^{cs}(x) = {\rm dim}\, E^{s}(x) + {\rm dim}\, E^{c}(x)$ which must be $< n$ because (by your assumption) $E^{u}(x) \neq \emptyset$. Here we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Dear @Evgeny, why a convergent trajectory to $x$ should belong to the center-stable manifold? Do you have any reference where I can find this result?

Comment: If you are assuming "the existence of only one eigenvalue with positive real part, not all of them", then you are assuming the existence of non-positive eigenvalues (but that is not given in the post)

Comment: @MauroPatrão You can read about it [here](https://labs.ni.gsu.edu/ashilnikov/pubs/part1.pdf), p. 281. Center-stable manifold is characterized by phrase "contains all points that stay forever in a small neighbourhood of equilibrium, for all positive times". Of course it also contains trajectories that go straight to the equilibrium.

Comment: Dear @Evgeny, thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MauroPatrão You are welcome! :)